# Form method Post not working

Tags: php, html

My problem seams to be simple, but I am struggling to get this to work.

Here's my html:

```
<form class="form" role="form" id="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url("register"); ?>" onsubmit="" >
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 fm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" 
      value="<?php if(isset($validation_errors['post_data']['email'])) echo $validation_errors['post_data']['email']; ?>" 
      placeholder="Email" >
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn" value="Quero ganhar um Cartão">
  </div>
</form>
```

I made the code a bit simple, so you could read it fast.
When I submit the form to the register page, I try to see if it is a post or not like this :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller {

 function Register() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('register_model');
 }


 public function index() {
  if($_POST) { echo 'post'; } else { echo 'not a post'; }
 }
}
```

And the controller keeps printing 'not a post'.
It seams like the form only redirect to the URL and do nothing more.

Edit :
I did `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];`  in my controller and it prints " GET ", so, I guess something is wrong with the method ? I Already tried `method="POST"`, `method="post"` and it keeps printing " GET ". Don't know what else to do.

Comment: Your English is fine.

Comment: What you call on `onsubmit="" `???

Comment: You can replace `<?php echo site_url("register"); ?>` By `<?= site_url("register"); ?>`

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron The site_url() is fine. It writes the url i expect

Comment: Y, but just for better syntax without echo.

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron Oh Ok ! Thanks ! It makes any difference in performance ? Or is just for a better looking syntax ?

Comment: Just for a better looking syntax ;)

Answer (score 1):

add url helper in controller, then only you can access `site_url()` in your view page

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

remove unnecessary `onsubmit=""` in your `form` tag

Comment: I can access  site_url() just fine. Like i said, it goes to the URL i expect it to go. But it doesn't go as POST

Answer (score 0):

i did manage to get this going.

My redirect link didn't have "www" on it, and despite the redirect, it needed the "www" to do the POST.

Thanks to everyone that tried to help !